# Repeating a background texture

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to use the graphic below and I would like to repeat from the right to continue on the boards.  What would my best options be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make this image the background of an css element and set property repeat-x.

`background: url("paper.gif") repeat-x;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-position property, like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZCl.jpg");
    background-position: right 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/72p5h6hs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the background might look a little funny so as an alternative you can use background-size:cover to make the image stretch the whole width of the screen.

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIZCl.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```